# How to capture the DataValueField of the autocomplete componet of kendoUI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

Hello I am working with Kendo UI, specifically with kendoAutoComplete component. I can get the value of autocomplete field, but I need the id value associated with it.

```
$("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
    minLength: 3,
    dataTextField: "Name", //JSON property name to use
    dataValueField: "Id",
    dataSource: respuestaSolicitud
});
```

I captured of this way

```
var x=$('#autocomplete').data("kendoAutoComplete");
```

Variable x return [object]

```
document.getElementById('autocomplete').value
```

return value of `dataTextField: "Name"`
But I need integer value `dataValueField: "Id"`

Answer (score -3):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            var data = [{Name:"aaaa",Id:1111},{Name:"bbbb",Id:2222}
            ];

            //create AutoComplete UI component
            $("#countries").kendoAutoComplete({
                dataSource: data,
                change: function(e){
                    alert(this.dataItem().Id)
                },
                dataTextField: "Name", //JSON property name to use
                dataValueField: "Id",
                filter: "startswith",
                placeholder: "Select country...",
                separator: ", "
            });
        });

        function _getValue(){

            alert($("#countries").data("kendoAutoComplete").value())
        }
```

```css
.info {
            display: block;
            line-height: 22px;
            padding: 0 5px 5px 0;
            color: #36558e;
        }

        #shipping {
            width: 482px;
            height: 152px;
            padding: 110px 0 0 30px;
            background: url('../content/web/autocomplete/shipping.png') transparent no-repeat 0 0;
            margin: 100px auto;
        }

        .k-autocomplete
        {
            width: 250px;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        .hint {
            line-height: 22px;
            color: #aaa;
            font-style: italic;
            font-size: .9em;
            color: #7496d4;
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.429/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.429/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.429/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.429/styles/kendo.dataviz.material.min.css" />

    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.429/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.429/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="example">

    <div id="shipping">
        <button onclick="_getValue()">press me</button>

        <label for="countries" class="info">Choose shipping countries:</label>

        <input id="countries" />

        <div class="hint">Start typing the name of an European country</div>

    </div>
```

you can use underscore to find the result

```
var selected = $("#countries").data("kendoAutoComplete").value();
var dataItem = _.find($("#$("#countries").data("kendoAutoComplete").dataSource.data(),function(element){
return element.Name=== selected;
})

alert (dataItem.Id)
```

another approach would be to use a change event and onthat event you get the full element with this.dataItem() so you get the Id with

```
this.dataItem().Id
```

Comment: In this code fragment is an error?
_.find($("#$("#autocomplete")

Comment: This code did not work me:

    var selected = $("#autocomplete").data("kendoAutoComplete").value();
//  var dataItem = _.find($("#autocomplete").data("kendoAutoComplete").dataSource.data(),function(element){
                var dataItem = _.find($("#autocomplete").data("kendoAutoComplete"), function(element){
                return element.Name== selected;
        });

        alert (dataItem.value )

System Error: TypeError: dataItem is undefined

Comment: have you added referense to underscorejs ? also check the snipet I added , it runs and returns what you need

Comment: also if you provide the data itself it migt help ,ore

Comment: Dan Kuida your code return name of country. I need Id (integer) no value of <input>.Thanks..

Comment: You can runthe code snipet - it return the ID of the selected Name , and also as you see from it returns the dataItem , so you can select the property you want.Please add you data and it will be easier to write the exact reply